# float' object is not subscriptable - Romberg's algorithm

Tags: python

I am a total rookie of programming, just to make it clear on the beginning. I was trying to code Romberg's algorithm, but there's an error that keeps popping out in line 8 - 'float' object is not subscriptable. I don't really get why it is not subscriptable - is the fault in other lines being wrong or there's en error just in that line? I've been trying to figure it out for a while, but no ideas.

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
i=0
j=0
def romberg(f,a,b,n,r=[i,j]):
h=b-a
r[i,j]=(h/2)[f(a)+f(b)]
for i in range(n):
    i=1
    h=0
    h=h/2
    sum=0
    for k in range(2**i-2):
        k=1
        sum=sum+f(a+k*h)
    r[0,0]=(1/2)*r[i-1,0]+(sum)*h
    for j in range(i):
        j=1
        r[i,j]=r[i,j-1]+(r[i,j-1]-r[i-1,j-1])/(4**j-1)

def f(a):
    return np.cos(90)
solution=romberg(f,0,np.pi,10,r=[0,0])
print(solution)
```

Comment: You've got a significant problem in your `for` loop: `for i in range(n): i=1` makes the for loop pointless.

Comment: The error message looks like it is referring to the way you are using the variable `r`. In the function definition you have `r=[i,j]` so `r` is a list with two elements. A few lines later you say `r[i,j] = ...` which doesn't make sense for `r` as a list with two elements.

Comment: There's clearly an indentation error, but I can't tell where the block is supposed to end. Indentation is part of Python's syntax; it's not optional.